# Plot timestamp distribution in a day over multiple dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

This seems like a trivial thing to solve, but every idea I have is very hacky. I have a series of timestamps that spans multiple days. What I'm interested in, is the distribution of these timestamps (events) within 24h: e.g., see whether there are more events in the morning.

My data is in a pandas.DataFrame, and the timestamp column has dtype `datetime[ns]`. I tried `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(data.timestamp.dt.time)`, but that gives an error. I also thought of subtracting the data from my timestamps so they all start on 'day 0', and formatting the X-axis in the plot to not show the date. Feels very clumsy. Is there a better way?

Comment: Post some code showing the 'hacky' way you've tried so far so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in distribution with resolution limited to e.g.
hours, you can:

- Create a new column with extracted *hour* from your source *timestamp*.
- Group your data by *hour*.
- Generate your plot.

As you failed to post any sample data, I'm not able to post any code.